# Sourcemap and break points in Chrome don't work

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs, source-maps

I'm trying to place breakpoints in transpiled code that has a source map, but every time I press a line to place a breakpoint, it cancels immediately.

Like here:

[image]

Is it a problem with the webpack configuration? Should I post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the webpack config I changed `devtool: 'eval-source-map',` to `devtool: 'source-map',` and now it works, but it generates a .map file for each transpiled file, which didn't happen before when it worked.

Edit:

also removing this from the config helped:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  sourceMap: true,
  compress: false,
  minimize: false,
  mangle: false
}),
```